# Make a yymmdd PHP string from a form-posted calender input

Tags: php, html, date

I have an html form handled by a PHP for making mysql queries. It has a calendar picker input.

The PHP gets POST data describing future events, date, location, country, name.

Each event will have an "eventid" identifier built by the PHP handler from characters found in the country, name, location and date values. Then it will create a new table with that eventid as a table name, and add a row with the values in a pre-existing table that acts as an index. Eventid would have to look like "SeComicStockholm140304" for example.

But the calendar picker outputs a format that isn't usable like a string, I can't substract or replace charactrs, so I can't add yymmdd in the "eventid" I define in the PHP. But I need these 6 digits in there.

A workaround would be to use select inputs for year, month and day in the form, and that way output a text/string, but I want to know if there's a way to extract 6 digits as a string from a date value so I can keep the calendar picker.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "the calendar picker outputs a format that isn't usable" - what format? why can't this be configured to output what you want?

Comment: you can use date('ymd', strttotime($time));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create string from `date` and `strtotime` functions of php

```
$phpstring=date('ymd',strtotime($_POST['your_date_input']));
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you, I had seen this date function and strtotime function but had no idea them both together could output something I could use as a string.